# Can you have two separate Apache servers running on the same system?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jira

Can you have two separate apache servers running on the same system in parallel, as long as they make use of different ports?

I have a system I need to install JIRA on, but the system is already in-use and running an Apache server for a separate project. The JIRA installer comes with a pre-configured apache tomcat server. If I just installed JIRA, would I run into a problem from the pre-existing apache server?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re asking about running two Apache Tomcat instances, then this is not a problem. Moreover you can share the same `CATALINA_HOME` between many separate instances of Tomcat, each with own `CATALINA_BASE`. I’m often running separate Tomcat instance per application on production servers. See [this init script](https://github.com/cvut/gentoo-overlay/blob/247356a5ce811dfe0d89b0311b9cdeb9a386c27e/dev-java/tomcat-scripts/files/runscript.sh) for a hint about parameters.

But if you’re asking about running Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat on the same server, then it’s a little bit trickier. Commonly used approach is to use a web server (Apache HTTP, nginx, …) as a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat. Then many applications can run under the same port and IP address. In case of Apache HTTP Server, see [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html).

Comment: they will be running under the same IP address, but different port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Apache HTTPD and Tomcat are 2 different servers. Also, JIRA doesn't run on port 80 so in this case there will not be a conflict for port numbers. If you want to expose your JIRA on port 80, you can use mod_proxy for the Apache HTTPD to relay the requests to the actual port JIRA is running on, so that it is transparent to the user.

So basically: Yes, you can run both Apache HTTPD and Apache Tomcat on the same machine if not using the same port.

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure if the original server is Apache or Tomcat. What if it's Tomcat - would that become a problem?